# Most of our Active Directory groups are missing when I go to add a group to a TFS collection

Tags: active-directory

We are rolling out TFS to other groups within our company and non of the other active directory groups show up in the ADD A WINDOWS USER OR GROUP dialog. We only have the one local domain and don't see this with other applications. Is there something about Windows groups and TFS that I am missing?

Comment: Have you tried attempting to add the group manually? They usually won't show up in the searchable lists until you do. Try adding with the full domain\user text.